# click count of a certain link in wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress, counter, custom-fields

Is it possible to count how many times a certain link in post has been clicked?

(for example purpose, let's say that the certain link has an ID named 'bla')

```
<a id="bla" href="#">download</a>
```

---

I got a feeling it should be possible by using `custom-fields/post-meta` (to keep the count), just like the `ever-so-popular` 'visitor count' trick. Unfortunately, I'm rather clueless about `PHP`s.

Comment: I mean you could use a database table with all the link IDs and a combination of jQuery and AJAX calls to keep track. It would create a slight delay because of the AJAX call so it might be noticeable.

Comment: This solution worked for me: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/258898/count-and-show-clicks-on-external-links-in-a-single-page-post

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It could be done with ajax call that updates post meta field before the link is followed. Example below registers ajax action for users that are not logged in, and increases `link_click_counter` custom field by 1 on each click. Link must have id attribute `countable_link`. This is a basic example that works for only one link in post. To use it as a plugin create file like `wp-content/plugins/click-counter /click-counter.php` and copy-paste example code, or put the code in `functions.php` inside theme folder. First time the link is clicked, new custom field `link_click_counter` will be created for that post, and there you can track how many clicks link has.

HTML:

```
<a id="countable_link" href="#">download</a>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Link Clicks Counter
*/

if ( is_admin() ) add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_link_click_counter', 'link_click_counter' );
function link_click_counter() {

    if ( isset( $_POST['nonce'] ) &&  isset( $_POST['post_id'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['nonce'], 'link_click_counter_' . $_POST['post_id'] ) ) {
        $count = get_post_meta( $_POST['post_id'], 'link_click_counter', true );
        update_post_meta( $_POST['post_id'], 'link_click_counter', ( $count === '' ? 1 : $count + 1 ) );
    }
    exit();
}


add_action( 'wp_head', 'link_click_head' );
function link_click_head() {
    global $post;

    if( isset( $post->ID ) ) {
?>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    jQuery(function ($) {
        var ajax_options = {
            action: 'link_click_counter',
            nonce: '<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'link_click_counter_' . $post->ID ); ?>',
            ajaxurl: '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>',
            post_id: '<?php echo $post->ID; ?>'
        };

        $( '#countable_link' ).on( 'click', function() {
            var self = $( this );
            $.post( ajax_options.ajaxurl, ajax_options, function() {
                window.location.href = self.attr( "href" );
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me as well, can you please let me know what I am missing?

Comment: Hi, I have tried the following but it does not seem to update? https://codepen.io/Cozmoz/pen/gjEBVJ

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to redirect all through a common PHP gateway and from there, redirect to the original page you wanted to redirect using `Header('Location: yourpage.html');`
In the gateway PHP page count the number by incrementing a saved value by 1.